# Add timecode to audio data

Tags: java, timestamp, audio-recording

I want to build a program in Java that takes in an audio file and dumps audio volume information to a CSV file along with a time stamp. I need this audio data to line up with other data that I am collecting that already has a time stamp. Any suggestions on how to approach a problem like this?

I am parsing the data from a JSON file down to a CSV so it is a little easier to look at here is a sample from a CSV file:

```
01-29-2014 00:00:00 GMT-05:00   0.0371  67  86.7    0
01-29-2014 00:01:00 GMT-05:00   0.0368  74  86.7    0
01-29-2014 00:02:00 GMT-05:00   0.0417  77  86.5    0
01-29-2014 00:03:00 GMT-05:00   0.0408  71  86.5    0
01-29-2014 00:04:00 GMT-05:00   0.0404  76  86.3    0
01-29-2014 00:05:00 GMT-05:00   0.037   71  86.2    0
01-29-2014 00:06:00 GMT-05:00   0.0411  73  86.2    0
01-29-2014 00:07:00 GMT-05:00   0.038   69  86.1    0
01-29-2014 00:08:00 GMT-05:00   0.0339  68  86  0
01-29-2014 00:09:00 GMT-05:00   0.0349  null    86  11
01-29-2014 00:10:00 GMT-05:00   0.0327  null    85.8    22
01-29-2014 00:11:00 GMT-05:00   0.0346  null    85.8    85
01-29-2014 00:12:00 GMT-05:00   0.0502  77  85.8    0
01-29-2014 00:13:00 GMT-05:00   0.0502  76  85.8    0
01-29-2014 00:14:00 GMT-05:00   0.0446  74  85.8    0
01-29-2014 00:15:00 GMT-05:00   0.0455  77  85.8    0
01-29-2014 00:16:00 GMT-05:00   0.0448  79  85.6    0
01-29-2014 00:17:00 GMT-05:00   0.0437  78  85.5    0
01-29-2014 00:18:00 GMT-05:00   0.0506  89  85.5    0
01-29-2014 00:19:00 GMT-05:00   0.0518  103 85.5    0
01-29-2014 00:20:00 GMT-05:00   0.0484  80  85.7    0
```

The time starts off as a UNIX timestamp and is being converted to this format with a script. I intend on the data that I pull from the audio to look similar to this with a timestamp in one column and audio level in another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, whenever i hear the word 'timestamp'. [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) comes to mind. This returns the [milliseconds passed since 1970](http://currentmillis.com). However in your case, if you want to measure where you are in a song relative to the beginning of the song you should probably use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) which is more accurate (and faster i believe). This will return the nano seconds to or from an arbitrary point (which you don't really care about), but you can get a 'delta' this way:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
... do something ...
long delta = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

If you want it to line up with other data that you already have can you post some of that data so we can see what format it has exactly?

Comment: Teo, I edited the question to show some of the CSV data....thanks for the suggestion. I haven't used nanoTime() before. I will look into it.

Comment: You mentioned a UNIX timestamp, that's exactly what System.currentTimeMillis() is (you have to be careful with the conversion between seconds and milliseconds).